# In IIB, How to change the values of Encoding and CCSID in the input message properties

Tags: ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus

In IIB,we have a Message flow, which has MQ Input node listening to receive input message.
We have to change the Input MQMD/Message properties like Encoding and CCSID to the values which I needed.
I have used 'Convert' property in the MQ Input node properties and set the properties of 'Convert encoding' and 'Convert coded character set ID', but it is not changing the values of Input request MQMD Encoding and CCSID.
Please suggest how I can change these values.
The reason behind is I need to use these properties in my Error handling message flow.

We connect the error handling to Input MQ Node catch terminal, from that we send a mail to our support group with the error details. In Error handling in one of the compute node it is using InputRoot.Properties.Encoding, InputRoot.Properties.CodeCharacterSetID, which are receiving as Encoding - 273, CCSID - 37. We are seeing Error emails with Junk characters instead of proper text. We are assuming because of these properties it is causing issue. And for other parameters Encoding - 536, CCSID - 1208 or Encoding - 536, CCSID - 437 it is working with no issues.

Comment: You can only change these only on the output nodes. Can you describe your flow/requirements a bit more detailed?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with IIB to know the terminology. It is a fact that if you do an MQGET with convert, the MQMD after the MQGET has successfully completed will contain the Encoding and CCSID that the message is now in. Is this the same thing as the "Input request MQMD" or is there perhaps an "Input response MQMD" that is the thing being changed by the successful MQGET?

Comment: We are receiving MQ input request to our message flow with CCSID - 37, and Encoding - 273, because of these input properties, we are seeing some issue in our Error handling, so we need to change these values when after IIB received the request to the field values CCSID,Encoding we needed using 'Convert' option in MQ Input node.
@DanielSteinmann

Comment: @Virat: But then I think your actual problem lies somewhere in the error handling code. Can you tell us more about the error handling and the problems you see there?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the missing info. Provide the information about the input CCSID/Encoding and describe the exact problem with the error handling.

Comment: Hi,

We connect the error handling to Input MQ Node catch terminal, from that we send a mail to our support group with the error details.
In Error handling in one of the compute node it is using InputRoot.Properties.Encoding, InputRoot.Properties.CodeCharacterSetID, which are receiving as Encoding - 273, CCSID - 37.
We are seeing Error emails with Junk characters instead of proper text. We are assuming because of these properties it is causing issue.
And for other parameters Encoding - 536, CCSID - 1208 or Encoding - 536, CCSID - 437 it is working with no issues.

Comment: @Virat - update your question with the details - don't put them in a comment. Also, can you show an example of some characters that cause the problem so we check whether they are really in the CCSID that they are labelled with.

Answer (score 0):

IIB uses UTF8 internally, and converts the input and output message automatically, when parsing and serializing, based on the CCSID value in the message headers and/or Properties. You need to be careful on output as CCSID defined in message headers can overwrite the one in the Properties.

If you see invalid characters after the conversion done by IIB, than the most likely cause is that the incoming MQ message has an incorrect CCSID, one that doesn't match the actual codepage used for the data.
The CCSID in the MQMD header is just for information, there is nothing in MQ or IIB ensuring that the source application actually used the codepage, it put in the MQMD, on the data it sent.